# No se solucionar los errores que me indica Google developers pagespeed js+css

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-maps

Estoy trabajando en una página web y ya está subida al hosting (pero como tengo que arreglar alguna cosilla aún, he cerrado el acceso). El tema es que lo abrí un momento para ver que me decía google en sus herramientas de velocidad de carga de una web, y me han salido unos errores que no he sabido solucionar. Es la primera vez que hago un proyecto web. Me dice que elimine los scripts aunque lo solucioné en su mayoría usando async entre el script y el src. El asunto es que con el script de la api de googlemaps, si uso el async, no me carga el mapa (el script v en index.php en vez de en header.php como van los otros para evitar que en las demás páginas salga un error por no tener el mapa). El código que tengo es este:

```
<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBzYZmy7TTQ0alw5b2QDJpMp-YssOdlH9M"></script>
```

También me dice esto de los css:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me dice que priorice el contenido visible pero imagino que eso desaparece cuando solucione lo anterior.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda y quedo a la espera de una respuesta :)

P.D: Por temas de privacidad oculté el enlace a la página en los css.

Comment: Hola @Dianne, te recomiendo encarecidamente que dividas tu pregunta actual de modo que quede un problema en cada pregunta, de modo que puedas marcar en cada caso la respuesta correcta. De otro modo, tal como está formulada actualmente, tu pregunta será cerrada por ser demasiado amplia. Recuerda: solo puede haber una respuesta correcta para cada pregunta, si pones tres problemas en la misma pregunta no se podrá marcar como correcta una sola respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por el aviso, disculpa el tener que haberme advertido... lo del css lo pongo con el javascript, ya que google me pone ambas cosas en el mismo nivel de error (es un único bloque para ellos). 

Si, lo de aceptar respuesta lo se, en mis anteriores preguntas cuando tuve la respuesta marqué la correcta ^-^

Gracias y ya edité, ahora añado la última cuestión en otro tema :)

Answer (score 0):

El tema es dónde colocar los `<script ... /script>`. La recomendación es ponerlos abajo del todo dentro del body antes de cerrarlo:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta...
       no poner script acá salvo que haya una razón de peso
  </head>
  <body>
    <... poner acá el contenido sin script
    ...
    <script ... acá sí van los scripts /script>
  </body>
</html>
```

La razón para recomendarte eso es que el navegador, al encontrar un tag `<script>` tiene que detenerse (o sea se bloquea) en su tarea de mostrar la página para cargar, procesar y ejecutar el js. En cambio al hacerlo al final de todo, se pueden hacer varias cosas en paralelo acelerando la velocidad en que se muestra el contenido.

### Optimizar el CSS y/o la carga de archivos externos

Otra cosa que hay que tener en cuenta es que cada link implica una conexión para traer el otro archivo. Una posibilidad (en el caso de querer acelerar la carga y mostrado de la página) es poner el contenido dentro del html. Eso es fácil cuando se está trabajando con PHP. Simplemente en vez de mostrar

```
<link src="archivo.css" ...
```

se debe abrir el archivo con un comando `file_read_content` o similar y mandar todo el contenido dentro de un par de tags `<script>`, `</script>`. Lo ideal es tener una versión del archivo.css que solo contenga los estilos usados (o tener un preprocesador de ello).

Cada uno deberá evaluar, en las distintas etapas de su proyecto si vale la pena ponerse con esta tarea y cuántos milisegundos serían los ahorrados.

Comment: El javascript que me detecta tras poner el async a los demás se encuentra al final del index.php, no en el header, para evitar problemas. La estructura es: header.php, index.php y footer.php . El header y el footer son llamados vía php en el index.php. El index.php tiene los enlaces al resto de las páginas del proyecto.

Es decir y simplificándolo, el index.php tiene todo pero el script que detecta está al final del index.php porque solo debe cargarse en esa plantilla.

Comment: Si se mira en "ver código fuente de la página" en el html generado ¿también se lo ve abajo del todo?

Comment: Si, también sale abajo, mira esta imagen de "ver código fuente de la página", la línea en la que se encuentra el script que me detecta:  http://i.imgur.com/Pt8CsmK.png  Lo que me sorprende es que los plugins metan tantísimo contenido en la web. Sus css etc se cargan antes que los mios, por eso está tan abajo el código.

Comment: Acerca de los css, el asunto es que utilizo varios predeterminados de bootstrap y luego tengo, aparte, mi css propio. El de bootstrap creo que se solucionaría (no lo se) si lograse que me cogiese el que tengo dentro de las carpetas del tema de wordpress. He intentado linkearlo muchas veces pero nunca me lo coge así que al final decidí ponerlo por url. Mi archivo de css supongo que tendré que minificarlo. Los otros dos css no son mios y los necesito para diversas cosas.

Comment: El tema con los reportes de google sobre velocidad es que te dicen todo lo que encuentran (eso está bien) y luego es uno el que tiene que decidir si vale la pena o no atender a ello en base a los problemas reales de velocidad que uno vea. Los css se pueden bajar localmente al servidor aunque no sean tuyos (siempre que la licencia lo permita). La técnica también se puede usar para incluir los javascript

Comment: Algo que me preocupa es que aunque en mi navegador, móvil etc se ve bien la web, en la previsualización de la velocidad de google sale la cabecera de un color diferente al que tengo puesto (es blanco y el que figura es negro. Usé un navbar-inverse de bootstrap y luego le cambié el color predeterminado a blanco). Además, me puntuarán el proyecto por lo que necesito arreglar los problemas sí o sí (estoy de prácticas) aunque es para un negocio real por lo que debe tener un buen acabado. ¿Como se si mi servidor me permite eso? Lo tienen en raiolanetworks, el hosting inicio ssd.

Comment: Si que he observado que la página carga algo lenta, si quito los javascript es mas rápida, pero bootstrap me obliga a tener un javascript de ellos y un jquery (algo que necesito también por el scroll, es jquery). Me interesa también que cargue mas rápido, aunque desde que puse los async si que va mas rápida.